# Lower case a word only if it's not all caps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to lowercase words in a string **only** is they're not in all caps?

For example this string:

`WOrd ABC Word wOrD WOrD`

Should return:

`Word ABC word word word`

**Note:** The first word should still get "sentence case".

I've tried the `humanize` and `titlecase` functions in rails but they also lowercase words that are all caps (which often represents some acronym and shouldn't get lowercased).

**Update:**

With the help of the answers below, this ended up solving this for me:

```
def fix(string)
  s = []
  string.split.each do |word|
    if word.swapcase != word.downcase
      s << word.downcase
    else
      s << word
    end
  end
  s = s.join(' ').chomp(' ')
  s[0] = s[0].capitalize
  return s
end
```

Comment: Worth waiting until you have enough reputation to answer your own question and then posting your update as an answer rather than including you answer in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll come back and update this thread.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably just have to check if the swapcase and lower case are identical

```
if word.swapcase != word.downcase
    s << word.downcase + " "
else
    s << word + " "
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
string = 'WOrd ABC Word wOrD WOrD'
string.split(' ').map.with_index {|w,i|
  /^[A-Z]+$/.match(w) ? w : i == 0 ? w.capitalize : w.downcase
}.join(' ')
```

Produces:

```
=> "Word ABC word word word"
```

Comment: It fails if there is only one word in the string. Ex: `WorD`

Comment: Curious. It works perfectly for me with one word in the string. `string="WorD"` returns `=> "Word"`

Comment: You're correct. I made a mistake in assigning the string var. Was printing out a different string.

Comment: Ahh... but it does fail if you have punctuation. If there is a `word, WORD, word` the middle `WORD,` gets converted to lowercase.

Comment: I was able to fix that by changing the regex to `/^[A-Z0-9!%&(),.<>;':"?']+$/` Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can use `.split(/(\W)/)` which splits on any non-word character and keeps the terms. Then `.join('')` again afterwards.

Comment: But that wouldn't work in cases of all punctuation. For example: `word, wo'rd, word! word? (word)` i.e. the proper spacing would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'WOrd ABC Word wOrD WOrD'

str.split.collect { |w| w.eql?(w.upcase) ? w : w.downcase }.join(' ').capitalize

=> "Word abc word word word"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating small methods that provide a human-readable name:

```
class String
  def all_caps?
    swapcase == downcase
  end

  def downcase_all_but_acronyms
    all_caps? ? self : downcase
  end
end
```

Then your answer is:

```
string.split.map(&:downcase_all_but_acronyms)
```